# Set attribute to a child element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set an id attribute "gradient" to child element of the main one, which is grabbed by its id of "bg-gradient" , with below code, seems simple but its not working. Code is below, and the id "bg-gradient" is the only one in the document. It should set an id of "gradient" to the next div class "bg-gradient" when click the edit button but doesn't.

```
editSwatch() {
 let elem = document.getElementById('#bg-gradient');
 elem.childElement.setAttribute("id","gradient");
}
```

[image: Console elements]

Any tips welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `childElement` property for the DOM element instead use `firstElementChild` property to get the first child. In addition to that remove `#` from the argument since [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Parameters) requires an id value and not a CSS selector.

```
editSwatch() {
 let elem = document.getElementById('bg-gradient');
 elem.firstElementChild.setAttribute("id", "gradient");
}
```

---

Or alternately you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to  get the element.

```
editSwatch() {
 document.querySelector('#bg-gradient > .bg-gradient').setAttribute("id", "gradient");
}
```

Comment: Yes that's fixed it, now sets the id on the child element Thanks

Answer (score 1):

change

`let elem = document.getElementById('#bg-gradient');` to

```
let elem = document.getElementById('bg-gradient');
```

and change

`elem.childElement.setAttribute("id","gradient");` to

```
elem.firstElementChild.setAttribute("id","gradient");
```

dont put #. It is used by jquery like `$("#bg-gradient")`